# NAudio WaveFileReader.ReadNextSampleFrame() returns invalid amplitudes

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I recorded note D to the wav file and want to get array of it's amplitudes. I started to play this note before beginning of recording, so there is no empty interval.
Then I used NAudio.WaveFileReader.ReadNextSampleFrame() to get it's amplitudes but have output with a lot of zeros and rarely encountered non zero values, e.g:

```
0 
0 
0.1312 
0 
0 
... a lot of zeros
0.12312 
0.123123 
0 
0 
..a lot of zeros 
0 
0.12312
```

This is not correct because Ableton shows that sound is wavy:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("record.wav"))
{

    var leftAmplitudes = new List<float>();
    var rightAmplitudes = new List<float>();
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.SampleCount; i++)
    {
        var sampleFrame = reader.ReadNextSampleFrame();
        leftAmplitudes.Add(sampleFrame[0]);
        rightAmplitudes.Add(sampleFrame[1]);
    }
}
```

Do you know how can I get actual amplitudes?

Comment: how do you output your values? Are you sure there is no rounding going on somewhere? If you directly output sampleFrame[0] (and [1]) with `Console.WriteLine`, do you get the same result? Because my very similar code works perfectly fine but I often get much smaller values. If that is not the issue, try to investigate what exactly you recorded. Is the data in your file 16bit? 24bit? 32bit? I could imagine that the Library is having trouble with 24bit PCM...  try to verify by converting it to 32bit float using e.g. Audacity or any other audio processing program

Comment: It ReadNextSampleFrame normalizes into floating point +-1.0. Are you sure the values are actually 0, or is that just how you're displaying them

Comment: @N4ppeL, looks like there was some problem with my audio file, another files can be processed without any problems